# Eye Lag Screws in TJI type joist for suspended ceiling

Tags: ceiling

So I want to install a drop ceiling in my basement, but I have these TJI/ I-beam type engineered wood floor joists and I know that you should almost never nail or screw into them on their bottom flange. So, How does someone install a suspended ceiling with these type of joists then?

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of something else, but wouldn't sheetrock be commonly hung on these beams to make ceilings with screws or nails?  I don't see how eye screws would be any worse?

Comment: Yes, but drywall screws are definitely a lot smaller in diameter than these eye screws.

Answer (score 1):

Suspended ceilings are lightweight enough that you can attach to the bottom rails. Just don't use fasteners so large that they're splitting things, and come in from below or pre-drill from the side.

If you're using particularly heavy tiles, feel free to run your anchors into the upper rail. That completely eliminates any concern of damage.

Comment: I did see on a DIY site or board someone suggest running them into the upper strand, but can't fine any info anywhere else about doing any such thing or any other recommendations either. You'd think that there would be more info and guidance about this somewhere as it's got to be a really common occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up screwing the lags into the upper strand. I feel it keep so much more of the JTI joist's integrity intact and it was only a little bit more work.